# Is my website being checked for vulnerabilities or being attacked?

Tags: vulnerability, audit, known-vulnerabilities, vulnerability-scanners, asp.net

I have a website running on windows hosting with plesk 11 version and website is based on .net 4.5 by default PHP is also active for this website but is not being used. I have disabled PHP as i am not sure if my website is being checked for vulnerabilities or being attached.

My logs show that my website is being accessed with following url

```
/cgi-bin/php-cgi?-d+allow_url_include%3Don+-d+safe_mode%3Doff+-d+suhosin.simulation%3Don+-d+disable_functions%3D%22%22+-d+open_basedir%3Dnone+-d+auto_prepend_file%3Dphp:%2F%2Finput+-d+cgi.force_redirect%3D0+-d+cgi.redirect_status_env%3D0+-n

2018-01-06 22:53:53 92.222.6.12 200 POST / %2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%30+%2D%6E HTTP/1.1

2018-01-06 22:54:00 92.222.6.12 302 POST /cgi-bin/php %2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%30+%2D%6E HTTP/1.1

2018-01-06 22:51:37 43.239.55.218   404 GET /wp-login.php - HTTP/1.1

2018-01-06 22:54:47 92.222.6.12 404 GET /cgi-bin/php.cgi %2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%30+%2D%6E HTTP/1.1
```

When i searched part of first url it looks looks `suhosin.simulation` and serach didnt came up with much while some links pointing to an attack.

Cane any one help me with this are these bots or someone is scanning website for vulnerabilities

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting strange HTTP requests for non-existing pages?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82596/why-am-i-getting-strange-http-requests-for-non-existing-pages), [Strange requests to web server](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40291/strange-requests-to-web-server). In summary: usual internet noise, i.e. attackers knocking on all doors to see if these can easily be opened. As long as your are not vulnerable you don't have to worry.