# PHP stuff requests on Node.js based web app?

Tags: web-application, php, node.js

We have a Node.js based web application, that has routes like:

`myapp.com/posts/[postId]`

We tracked strange requests, which lead to 404 on this routes. The requests were to routes like:

```
/posts/phpinfo.php
/posts/.user.ini
/posts/info.php3
/posts/phptest.php
```

Neither we're using PHP nor do i know anything about it...

To me it seems that a crawler/bot is requesting these routes, using some PHP related stuff as `postId`s which makes no sense (to me)...

Is this legit, though useless, or a security related issue?

What could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic case of an attacker scanning your website to look for any interesting directories or files that may lead to exploitation. I can say that this happens to a very high percentage of websites online.

The hacker is running a not so sophisticated directory scan and is using the `.php` extension by default.

As mentioned in the comments, [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82596/why-am-i-getting-strange-http-requests-for-non-existing-pages) question may be able to give you additional information.